# Parsing JSON file and storing into Backbone Collection, Error: __ is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am parsing a JSON file with getJSON and storing the results in an array of models.  After which I am putting this array of models in a collection called data.

```
var DataArray = [];
var url = 'file.json';

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {

   for (var i = 0; i < json.var.length; i++) {
       var VarSamp = new DataModel();
       for (var j = 0; j < json.var[i].vartwo.length; j++) {

           VarSamp.set({'attr_1': json.var[i].attribute1});
           VarSamp.set({'attr_2': json.var[i].attribute2});
           VarSamp.set({'attr_3': json.var[i].vartwo[j].attribute3});

           DataArray.push(VarSamp);
       }

   }   

});

var data = new DataCollection(DataArray);
console.log(data);
```

When trying to then access my collection from the view, I receive the error: TypeError: 'data' is undefined.

Here is my view:

```
var dataCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.content',

    initialize:function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var source = $('#view-temp').html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(data.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
    }

});
```

Comment: which one is it, in your title you say "_" is not defined but then you later say "data" is undefined.

Comment: my apologies, it is "data".  In the title, I added "__" because of the lack of context.

Comment: No worries :) I just thought that you were talking about the underscore library which uses the namespace of "_". Anyways it looks like "data" is never defined in the render function. You need to pass "data" into your render function.

Comment: If I make data a global collection that accepts an array of models with pre-defined values, it works well.  I don't understand why I need to define it in the render function now though

Comment: I would avoid globals, it is not a good practice. What you could do instead is pass the data collection into your view such as `var view = new dataCollectionView(data)` which will let you access `data` in your `initialize` function and then you can pass it into `render()`

Comment: Every time you do a "set" on your model, you're basically overwriting the previous value. I'd look into collections and create/push models to it for each iteration.

Comment: @Sean: Don't you mean `var view = new dataCollectionView({ collection: data })`?

Comment: @muistooshort I think you're right. The initialize function would then get the `options` object. Then you could access your data by `options.collection`

Comment: @Sean: ["There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: ..., `collection`, ..."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).

Comment: Thank you both, new dataCollectionView({collection: data}) worked.  I then passed a this.collection into render and it displayed the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to pass `data` into your view.

```
var view = new dataCollectionView({collection: data});
```

followed by

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.render(options.collection);
}
```